# Sql Query: how to solve this query issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i've this two tables:

Table 1

> Key,  CenterId,  Value
>
> 01    Center A     10
>
> 02    Center B     100
>
> 03    Center C     50

and

Table 2

> ```
> Center,  SubCenter, A-Field,  B-Field
> Center A   Sub 1      ...     ...
> Center A   Sub 2
> Center A   Sub 3      ...     ...
> ```

I need to get ONE ROW per Center (one row from Table 1) and, all the subcenters but without duplicating row ... so my last result must be:

Query Result

> ```
>  Center,  Value, List-of-SubCenter
>  Center A,  10,   Sub1 Sub2 Sub 3
>  Center B, 100,   Sub4 ...  Sub N
> ```

How to do this in Sql (in particular SQL-SERVER) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for SQL Server 2005 and upwards

```
SELECT t1.centerid, t1.value, LEFT(el.sublist, LEN(el.sublist)-1) AS subcenters 
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t2.subcenter + ',' AS [text()]
             FROM Table2 t2
             WHERE t2.center = t1.centerid 
             FOR XML PATH(''))el(sublist)
```